# how can I have multiple tabbed boxes on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling to get multiple instances of this tabbed box on one page. I am very new to jquery, and the code I have is copied. The tabbed box works fine, but multiple instances cause problems.

The HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
    <li class="active" rel="tab1"> Single Wall Cases</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Double Wall Cases</li>
    <li rel="tab3">Heavy Duty Cases</li>
    <li rel="tab4">Wardrobe Cartons</li>
    <li rel="tab5">Archive Boxes</li>
    <li rel="tab6">Stitched Wallets</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container"> 

 <div id="tab1" class="tab_content"> 

     <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
     <strong>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
     </strong>
     </p>

 </div><!-- #tab1 -->
 <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/web size/Pillow Pak'R 1web.jpg" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab2 -->
 <div id="tab3" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab3 -->
 <div id="tab4" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab4 --> 

 <div id="tab5" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab5 -->


 <div id="tab6" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab6 -->
```

The CSS:

```
ul.tabs {
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
list-style: none;
height: 32px;
/* [disabled]border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; */
/* [disabled]border-left: 1px solid #999999; */
width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-bottom: 0;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0px 21px;
height: 31px;
line-height: 31px;
border-color: rgba(37,37,37,1.00);
border-left-style: solid;
/* [disabled]border-right-style: solid; */
/* [disabled]border-bottom-style: solid; */
/* [disabled]border-top-style: solid; */
border-width: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
font-family: abel;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
color: rgba(37,37,37,1.00);
float: left;
}
ul.tabs li:hover {
background: #CCCCCC;
color: rgba(37,37,37,1.00);
}   
ul.tabs li.active{
background-color: #8DDF2D;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
color: rgba(37,37,37,1.00);
}
.tab_container {
border: 1px solid #999999;
clear: both;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
.tab_content {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 1.2em;
display: none;
}


@media (max-width: 600px){
ul.tabs li {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 77%;
float: none;
width: 92px;
}
ul.tabs {
}
.tab_container {
margin-top: 175px;
}
```

And the Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
 });
});

</script>
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdy96pvg)!

I have multiple section tags on my page, and would like this tabbed box in each section.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I recommend putting your code within a **snippet** that can be found within the text editor or putting it within a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for the tip :) I will do that now.

Comment: Here is your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hdy96pvg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of the Tabs you wish to have. Check out the code snippet. I hope that is what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
 });
});
```

```css
ul.tabs {
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
list-style: none;
height: 32px;
/* [disabled]border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; */
/* [disabled]border-left: 1px solid #999999; */
width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-bottom: 0;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0px 21px;
height: 31px;
line-height: 31px;
    display:inline;
border-color: rgba(37,37,37,1.00);
border-left-style: solid;
/* [disabled]border-right-style: solid; */
/* [disabled]border-bottom-style: solid; */
/* [disabled]border-top-style: solid; */
border-width: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
font-family: abel;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
color: rgba(37,37,37,1.00);
float: left;
}
ul.tabs li:hover {
background: #CCCCCC;
color: rgba(37,37,37,1.00);
}   
ul.tabs li.active{
background-color: #8DDF2D;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
color: rgba(37,37,37,1.00);
}
.tab_container {
border: 1px solid #999999;
clear: both;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
.tab_content {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 1.2em;
display: none;
}


@media (max-width: 600px){
ul.tabs li {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 77%;
float: none;
width: 92px;
}
ul.tabs {
}
.tab_container {
margin-top: 175px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs"> 
    <li class="active" rel="tab1"> Single Wall Cases</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Double Wall Cases</li>
    <li rel="tab3">Heavy Duty Cases</li>
    <li rel="tab4">Wardrobe Cartons</li>
    <li rel="tab5">Archive Boxes</li>
    <li rel="tab6">Stitched Wallets</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container"> 

 <div id="tab1" class="tab_content"> 

     <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
     <strong>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
     </strong>
     </p>

 </div><!-- #tab1 -->
 <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/web size/Pillow Pak'R 1web.jpg" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab2 -->
 <div id="tab3" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab3 -->
 <div id="tab4" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab4 --> 

 <div id="tab5" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab5 -->


 <div id="tab6" class="tab_content"> 

   <p><img src="../images/round images/boxes1.png" width="200"> <br />
    <strong>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ultrices vel felis id pulvinar. Aliquam vulputate auctor luctus. Etiam nisl lectus, tempor eu justo sit amet, vestibulum viverra ante. Mauris sed condimentum tortor. Duis sed pharetra turpis. Aliquam pulvinar ante quam, ut lobortis dolor faucibus rhoncus. Nullam quis velit nunc. Phasellus aliquam, diam nec finibus blandit, ligula est molestie risus, iaculis pellentesque ipsum magna ut neque. Duis tempus, justo non rhoncus rhoncus, nibh ligula sagittis enim, in pellentesque metus enim at eros. Aenean sit amet ipsum vitae sem tempus fermentum. Vivamus pharetra, metus id hendrerit ultrices, nisl elit congue nunc, non gravida ante mi ac nisl. Cras viverra luctus neque. Cras et dolor imperdiet, dapibus velit sit amet, feugiat nunc. Curabitur iaculis felis vitae convallis ornare.
    </strong>
   </p>

 </div><!-- #tab6 -->
```

The issue was with `display` attribute in css

Comment: Thanks @sooraj Chandran. Am I right in thinking that all I need to do is change the link id's so not to have them all function together on click?

Comment: @MattDelahoussaye Here is the working example of your code - http://jsfiddle.net/hdy96pvg/

Comment: @MattDelahoussaye the javascript in your code is fine. Issue was with css `display` attribute

Comment: I also just figured that issue out :) I have this working in my page now, Thank you very much for your help @Sooraj Chandran, and everyone else.